# Can a TorndaoFx tableview column have a datepicker as the input method?

Tags: tornadofx

I've got a tableview with a column that binds to a SimpleObjectProperty (LocalDate) variable:

```
tableview(Model) {
    column("DATE",Model::date).makeEditable()
    ...
}
```

I would like to make it a date picker to allow easy access for the user, something like the following:

```
tableview(Model) {
    column("DATE",Model::date).makeEditable().datepicker()
    ...
}
```

Although I'm not sure what the right syntax is, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your domain object has an id, you can create a cached cell with a datepicker in it like this:

```
column("DATE", Model::dateProperty) {
    cellFormat {
        graphic = cache(rowItem.id) {
           datepicker(rowItem.dateProperty)
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do this without the use of a cache, but performance won't be great for big datasets.